# "Did you mean" in git

Tags: algorithm, git, artificial-intelligence, copy-paste

I want to write a "Did you mean" algorithm.
I have a set of words (Just like git commands such as *pull*, *push*, *clone*).
I need to give suggestions whenever users are entering a word out of the set of words.
All above details are background of my question :)

[image: "Do you mean" in git]

I want to copy ;) the code used in the git to implement 'Did you mean' algorithm to accomplish my task.
Do you know the location of the git-source-file containing the 'Did you mean' algorithm ?

Comment: I'm guessing it isn't that hard to do this without git source code.  1) Get second arg, 2) See if it matches a command, 3) If it doesn't, present a list of all commands that begin with the same first letter.

Comment: Are you sure you will not be infringing git's [GPL2](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/COPYING) license? Where and how will your code be used? Will you distribute it?

Comment: @dtryon That's a miserable algorithm (produces lots of useless or seemingly unrelated results, while rarely hitting what you really meant) compared to decent edit-distance algorithms such as Levenshtein.

Comment: @dtryon Thanks yaar to give us such an idea.

Comment: @delnan  dtryon's method may give only less than 50% accuracy. We shouldn't ignore the fact that there is no algorithm for did-you-mean with 100% accuracy.

Comment: @sch Let us(novice programmers) live with copy-paste mantra :)

Comment: @delnan Miserable, yes.  Simple, yes.  I guess it depends on requirements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant code is in [`levenshtein.c`](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/levenshtein.c) (edit distance computation) and [`help.c`](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/help.c) (cutoff).

Comment: Great! How did you find the location? Do you have any tool other than my grep-tool?

Comment: @habeebperwad When I looked for this a while back, I probably just did `git grep 'Did you mean one of these'` and traced the code from there.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with plurality, since if only a single command matches it instead says "Did you mean this?"

Answer (score 2):

Iarsmans already gave you a link to the implementation of the algorithm in git, but if you wish to read something about the theory you may want to read the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) and [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) pages on wikipedia.

To put it simply, for an edit distance algorithm, the aim is to calculate -- given a set of basic edit operations on the data type you're working on (strings in your case) -- the minimum number of edits to make one value (string) identical to the other one.